# Excel Sort data in symmetrical fashion

Tags: excel, sorting

My data is output (Low to High) as follows:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5
```

I want to sort it symmetrically so the output becomes:

```
5
4
3
2
1
1
2
3
4
5
```

The reason is I need to delete half the data from my new order. This is much easier than deleting every other line from my original output.

In reality I am talking about several thousand lines with hundreds of distinct values.

Can you help me with custom formula I can put in a temporary column or better solution?

Thanks

Comment: So those numbers are in one column, one cell, one row?

Comment: If in one column, no need to sort, just use Remove Duplicates on the Data tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the values are in column **A** and are always in **pairs**.

In **B1** enter:

```
=A1
```

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2=A1,-A1,A2)
```

and copy downward.  Then copy column **B** and PasteSpecialValues onto itself.

[image]

Then sort columns **A** & **B** by **B**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This solution is best for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have more than just duplicated elements or otherwise there are also unique numbers. I would propose the next scheme:

1. Use `COUNTIF` function with fixed beginning row and flexible closing row;
2. Apply `IF` with `ISODD` function to equally separate numbers and to not delete unique ones (like this `=IF(ISODD(B2),A2,-A2)`);
3. Sort.

[image]

**Note**: If you just need to delete duplicates - use built-in features.